# difference command in python3 console and python3 program code

Tags: python, ubuntu, os.system, wmctrl

I write a program in python3.6 under PyCharm in Ubuntu 18.04
I want to pop up a jpg-file on specific window-coordinates. The only possible way to do this seems to be usage of eog and wmctrl.

I did not find an imageviewer, who is able to position the jpg-file exatly where i want (not eog, qiv, ..or others, they miss these options)

So I use 
`eog filename.jpg` to pop ist up.
Then the `wmctrl-command` to place it on the screen

Doing on console in unix(Ubuntu):

`eog filename.jpg` -->   eog pops it up centered.

`wmctrl -a filename.jpg -e 0,10,0,600,2000`  --> places it, where I want

(It doesn't matter from which directory I call eog, it also can be with directory /home/user/......(filename.jpg). For wmctrl in each case only filename.jpg is sufficent. (Also "wmctrl -r filename.......  works)

Doing the same from Pythone-console, it works perfectly, too.

But: when I do the some from programcode with

`cmd = "eog filename.jpg"`

`os.system(cmd)`  (or `os.system("cmd")`, pop-up of the file centered on the screen works

BUT:

`cmd = "wmctrl -a filename.jpg -e 0,10,0,600,2000"`

`os.systems(cmd)`  -------> nothing happens, as if the `os.system()` command is ignored

Any idea, what could be wrong is appreciated  !

(I first thought, I run into problems with filename and specific characters, but it also happens with simple names like test.jpg or so.)

on Python-console i also use 
`cmd =...........`   and
`os.system(cmd)` after `"import os"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry: I solved it by myself.

It only needs a pause before the wmctrl-command is fired !

import time

time.sleep(2)      does the job (may be, 1 second also is enough)

(doing it on the console, through typing you get the pause automatically)

Comment: You need to indent your code when you post so that it is more readable to others. Also, blocks of relevant code shouldn't be intermingled with text.